# Remove element from Binary Search Tree in F#

Tags: types, f#, functional-programming, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a method to delete an element from a BST. So far, this is what I have. It is almost working. It works for when the node to be deleted has 1 child and for when it has no children, but when there are 2 children I am having a problem. I want to replace that node's value with the smallest item on it's right subtree, and then remove the smallest item on its right subtree, just like a normal BST remove algorithm.

```
type 'a bst = NL | BinTree of 'a * 'a bst * 'a bst;;

let rec smallest = function
    | NL -> failwith "tree is empty"
    | BinTree(m, lst, rst) -> if lst = NL then BinTree(m, lst, rst)
                              else smallest lst;;

let rec smallest2 = function
    | NL -> failwith "tree is empty"
    | BinTree(m, lst, rst) -> if lst = NL then m
                              else smallest2 lst;;

let rec rem2 = function
    | NL -> NL
    | BinTree(m, NL, NL) -> NL
    | BinTree(m, NL, rst) -> rst
    | BinTree(m, lst, NL) -> lst
    | BinTree(m, lst, rst) -> BinTree(smallest2 rst, lst, rst)
                              rem2 (BinTree(m, lst, rst));; //error in my syntax


let rec rem x = function
    |NL -> failwith "Node doesn't exit"
    |BinTree(m, lst, rst) -> if m = x then rem2 (BinTree(m, lst, rst)) 
                             elif m < x then BinTree(m, lst, rem x rst) 
                             else BinTree(m, rem x lst, rst);;
```

Comment: I think the issue is in `rem2` which is pretty close - you just forgot to remove smallest from `rst` (which you should be able to do rather easy)

Comment: yes I agree! I am trying but I'm getting an error in my syntax. I'm not sure how to write it in F#

Comment: you probably wanted to do it with `rem` right? In this case you have to introduce *mutable recursion*: `let rec rem2 = function ...` and then later `and rem x = function ...` instead of `let rec rem x ...` - the first `let` and the later `and` should be on the same column

Comment: anyway: if you give me an example (to lazy to write it ;) ) - I'll fix your code and answer it ... but on first glance it would be ok to just use `smallest` in there